# Programming Zebra's RS507 Barcode Scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner

Does anyone know how one can program an RS507 scanner from Zebra. I noticed in the manual that they mentioned Zebra had a utility known as 123Scan, but when I went to their download webpage, the RS507 isn't included under compatible devices.

Are there any alternatives to creating an advance data formatting file the RS507?

Answer (score 0):

123Scan is used to configure scanners but as you say, RS507 is not one of the scanners that software supports.  You can configure the RS507 by scanning the barcodes in the Product Reference guide https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/rs507-prg-en.pdf.  If you are using a Zebra mobile computer the EMDK supports programmatic access http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-8/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.ReaderParams.ReaderSpecific.ImagerSpecific.html as does DataWedge.